# Winter Bash top bar not responsive enough on very narrow screens

Tags: bug, responsive-design, winter-bash-2018

I like the responsiveness of the [Winter Bash page](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/), but I found one small problem: on very narrow screens, the user information in the top bar will shift down and overlap the Winter Bash logo:

[image]

It's probably better not to display the username in this case, like what happens on the Q&A sites where reputation and badges are hidden on narrow screens.